# Creating a responsive barchart in amchart v4

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, amcharts

So I read on the docs that responsiveness for amchart 4 is still currently under development, and so perhaps that explains my difficulties here.

I'm trying to create a barchart that will shrink properly without distorting how the data is displayed. I've tried shrinking the parent container with an @media rule, but that distorted the data.

What's happening: When I shrink the view (i.e. open up inspector or run the web app on a smaller machine) half the category labels on the X-axis are disappearing for some strange reason. It seems to be every other label exactly is gone.

I've tried setting:

```
categoryAxis.minWidth = 0;
```

As an approximation of v3's minHorizontalGap property but of course they aren't the same.

I've tried setting the column width in hoped that that would influence the labels.

```
series.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(50);
```

And finally I've tried setting both the whole chart to responsive, and the categoryAxis:

```
categoryAxis.responsive.enabled = true;
```

But doing this gives me the following error which I can't find support for online:

```
bootstrap:114 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Loading chunk vendors~responsivedefaults failed.
```

I'm not sure what the problem is or how to resolve it, I can't believe they'd release a version of amcharts that didn't have responsivity in this age, and so I think it has to be something I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the v4 equivalent to minHorizontalGap and that has solved the problem for me.

```
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 60;
```

It's as simple as that. I still don't know why responsive.enabled doesn't work, but this is a satisfactory solution.

Comment: I've been having problems setting responsive.enabled to true, and so this was the only solution I found.

Comment: Oh I see now, that `bootstrap:114` line. I'll make a note of it. Sorry about that.